# How to create a list of lists in NetLogo?

Tags: syntax-error, netlogo, nested-lists, agent-based-modeling

I want to create a list of lists in NetLogo. What I have is the following:

```py
let a []
let b []
let c []
let d []
let l-o-l list [a b c d]
```

But then I get :

*`LIST expected 2 inputs on the right or any inputs when surrounded by parentheses.`*

with the `list` highlighted.

But when I change the last line to `let l-o-l list (a b c d)`,
I have the `b` highlighted with *`Expected closing parenthesis.`*

I am confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close!  What you want is

```
(list a b c d)
```

When there is more than the normal number of inputs, it is the whole expression that is enclosed, including the `list` reporter.